# nameerror model post not defined

Tags: django, django-models

## Problem

i created a model for my project after making it when i register it in admin.py file it throughs a name error.says 'post' not defined

## Error

NameError: name 'Post' is not defined

```
class Post(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   message=models.TextField()
   message_html=models.TextField(editable=False)


   group=models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='posts',
                        null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.message
   def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
       self.message_html=misaka.html(self.message)
       super().save(*args,**kwargs)
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('posts:single',kwargs= 
                    {'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})
   class meta:
       ordering=['-created_at']
       unique_together=['user','message']
```

Comment: Do you use Post as Foreignkey/OneToOne key relation with another model ?

Comment: post the contents of `admin.py`

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the Post model to admin.py? Most probably, you have not and that's why it's undefined there:

```
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```